# About naajasah (impurity) transfer

Tags: sharia, taharah, masturbation, najis

I didn't knew masturbation was haram so I masturbated  and something was released from me so i touched that liquid and without that liquid on my hand i touched my blanket, mosquito net but after a while i came to know that its haram and i have to take gusal but i didn't take gusal i just washed my private part and performed wudu and prayed the Fazar salat and later i took gusal and prayed on the same prayer rug or mat so did i became impure again by coming in contact with the prayer mat and if i touch the mosquito net, blanket(mentioned before) will i become impure and if another garment touches that mosquito net, blanket will that garment become impure too and if the garment becomes impure and if that garment touches my clothes will my clothes become impure too?